# How many eyes do we have?

Tags: logical-deduction

If a giraffe has two eyes, a monkey has two eyes, and an elephant has two eyes, how many eyes do we have?

The question is not guess work.. it has definite answer.

Comment: I suspect there's some trickery regarding who "we" is.

Comment: Yes @F1Krazy your going well;)

Comment: This seems like what it's really asking is "guess what specific and possibly-unexpected thing I mean by 'we'". That's not a _puzzle_, it's a joke or a trick.

Comment: this isn't guess question it has specific answer.. if you are not sure you can wait for the answer... there was no reason to downvote or close the question.. atleast give others time to explain themselves...

Comment: The answer is 2 right? Because when we say how many eyes does giraffes have or humans have, we say it is 2.

Comment: @MsDesigner You shouldn't post answers in comments, not even for your own questions. Archipelago got the answer right, so ideally you should accept their answer as correct (you should see a green tick mark next to their answer that you can click to accept it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> maybe 4 or 10, if 4: the asker and the one who answers together, if 10: sum of the eyes of every creature in the group (3 animals+2 humans)

Comment: One of this is correct answer... we need to find it ;)

Comment: most likely your intention is 4 :)

Comment: why can't I see the upvote button to vote the answer